# What is this 2 DoF joint called?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm looking for the common name(s) or other unique information of a 2 DoF pendulum joint that has one rod that pivots about one axis, connected to a fork that pivots about the orthogonal axis, which mounts to a fixed frame. The main rod extends all the way through the joint. Moving the rod in the x/y direction above the joint gives inverted movement on the opposite side.

Below is the best example of such a joint I could find. Here the rod appears to be in two parts (threaded rod on top, black plastic below), but they move as one piece.

[image: Joint]

Comment: A universal joint?

Comment: @philsweet why don't you turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These joints are called gimbals. The main idea is that the pivots are nested. There is an outer pivot, and the frame inside contains another pivot, and so on.

> A gimbal is a pivoted support that permits rotation of an object about
> an axis. A set of three gimbals, one mounted on the other with
> orthogonal pivot axes, may be used to allow an object mounted on the
> innermost gimbal to remain independent of the rotation of its support
> (e.g. vertical in the first animation). For example, on a ship, the
> gyroscopes, shipboard compasses, stoves, and even drink holders
> typically use gimbals to keep them upright with respect to the horizon
> despite the ship's pitching and rolling.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal